# Interesting and fun eigenvalue problem for a matrix $B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been thinking about ways on how to tackle this particular linear algebra problem related to eigenvalues from an old algebra prelim. The problem is that suppose we are given a matrix $B \in M_{n}(\mathbb{Q})$ such that $B^5 =I$, i.e. the $n \times n$ identity matrix, and no eigenvalue of $B$ is equal to $1$. We have to show that $n$ is divisible by $4$.

My attempt: I take it that $B^5 =I \implies B^5 -I=0$ (the zero matrix). Now by definition, the eigenvalues of a matrix $B$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $c_B(x)$ of $B$ and we also know that $c_B(x)$ annihilates the matrix $B$, i.e. $c_B(B)=0$. Now in this problem, the key condition is that $1$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $B$, so does this mean, via the factorization $$x^5 -1= (x-1)(x^4 +x^3 +x^2 +x+1)$$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, that $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 +x+1$ divides $c_B(x)$, which has degree $n$? Is this enough to say that $n$ is divisible by $4$, or are there any other necessary things to be considered carefully before coming to that conclusion?

Comment: Interesting *but* tricky? I don‘t get that part.

Comment: Probably just missing something really simple, perhaps not that tricky. Interesting might be the better way to put it.

Comment: "Interesting *but* tricky" somewhat implies that normally "interesting" and "tricky" don‘t go well together. I don‘t agree with that. ;)

Comment: I changed it to "interesting and fun."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $B^5 = I$, the minimal polynomial of $B$ over the rationals divides 
$x^5 - 1$.  Now $x^5 - 1 = (x - 1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)$, where 
$x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ is irreducible (it's the fifth [cyclotomic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)), and since $1$ is not an eigenvalue the minimal polynomial can only be $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$.  All irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial divide the minimal polynomial, so the characteristic polynomial is 
a power of $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$, and this implies that $n$ is a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 3):

All eigenvalues of $B$ are (complex) fifth roots of unity, and since $1$ is excluded they must be $\omega,\omega^{-1},\omega^2,\omega^{-2}$, where
$$\omega=e^{2\pi i/5}\ .$$
The characteristic polynomial of $B$ has the form
$$(z-\omega)^a(z-\omega^{-1})^b(z-\omega^2)^c(z-\omega^{-2})^d\ ,$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are non-negative integers and $a+b+c+d=n$.  However this polynomial must have rational coefficients, which forces $a=b=c=d$; so $n=4a$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Oh that's right. $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x+1$ is the fifth cyclotomic polynomial and the minimal polynomial of primitive fifth root of unity.

Comment: Not sure that's exactly the point.  If $B$ were allowed to have complex entries then $a,b,c,d$ could be anything.  And if it were allowed to have real entries, then $a=b$ and $c=d$ but there would be no reason for all four to be equal.  So it is essential that we are talking about a matrix with rational entries.

Comment: To be clear, your argument only works for $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$, am I correct?

Comment: No, it only works for $M_n(\Bbb Q)$.  In $M_n(\Bbb C)$ we could have any value for $n$, in $M_n(\Bbb R)$ any even value.